# Numpy syntax for mean

Tags: python, numpy

While using python / numpy I came across the following syntax:

```
np.mean(predicted == docs_test.target)
```

where the arguments are of type `numpy.ndarray`

What is the meaning of `==` here?

Thanks,
Jaideep

Comment: If this question has been answered to your satisfaction, please accept one of the answers by clicking the green checkmark next to the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `predicted` and `docs_test.target` are two arrays of the same size, this computes the fraction of elements where the two arrays are in exact agreement.

For example,

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [3]: b = np.array([1, 3, 7, 4, 5, 0, -10])

In [4]: np.mean(a == b)
Out[4]: 0.42857142857142855
```

This is telling us that in ~43% of cases (3 out of 7), `a` and `b` are in agreement.

Comment: @user2231929 To see what's happening inside: `In [5]: a == b`;
`Out[5]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)`

Answer (score 2):

If both `predicted` and `docs_test.target` are numpy arrays, then `==` will return a new array with `1` in place of matching elements and `0` where the elements differ. `mean` of that array will give you a measure of similarity, basically `numberofmatchingelements / lengthofpredictedarray`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#arithmetic-and-comparison-operations):

> Each of ... the comparisons (`==`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `!=`) is
>   equivalent to the corresponding universal function

In this case the corresponding universal function is [`numpy.equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html#numpy-equal):

> `numpy.equal(x1, x2[, out])`
>
> Return (`x1 == x2`) element-wise.